# Getting input type file image in typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, file, upload, fabricjs

I am having trouble getting the file that is stored in input typed "file" to use on Fabric JS canvas.

The flow of the process is supposed to be like so:

- User press button (calls onAddImage)
- User choose image to upload
- Image added to canvas in Fabric JS

Here is what I have done so far in TS:

```
const onAddImage = () => {
    document.getElementById("image-file")?.click(); //Invoke image file upload
    const fileInput = document.getElementById( // Get file input 
      "image-file"
    ) as HTMLInputElement | null;
    


    // file?.files?.[0] // This what I tried using with no avail to get the image



    if (fileInput) {
      fabric.Image.fromURL(<local image PATH supposed to be HERE>, function (img) { // Image path supposed to go here
        editor?.canvas.add(img);
      });
    }};
```

How do I add the image from input type file into the function as string if the image does not exist in local directory? Do I need to save the image in cache of some sort? FabcricJS has 2 more functions ([fromObject and fromElement](http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.Image.html)) too, but Im not sure if that is needed here.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<b> Image from Local PC: </b>
    <input id="fileInput" type="file" accept="image/*" onchange="Upload()" />
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/4.5.0/fabric.min.js"> </script>
    <canvas id="canvas" width="1024px" height="576px" style="border:1px solid red"> </canvas>

    <script>
        var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvas');
        function Upload() {
            var input = document.getElementById("fileInput");
            var file = input.files[0];
            if (file) {
                var reader = new FileReader();
                reader.onload = function (event) {
                    var imgObj = new Image();
                    imgObj.src = event.target.result;
                    imgObj.onload = function () {
                        canvas.add(new fabric.Image(imgObj))
                    };
                };
                reader.readAsDataURL(file);
            }
        }
    </script>
```

```js
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvas');
        function Upload() {
            var input = document.getElementById("fileInput");
            var file = input.files[0];
            if (file) {
                var reader = new FileReader();
                reader.onload = function (event) {
                    var imgObj = new Image();
                    imgObj.src = event.target.result;
                    imgObj.onload = function () {
                        canvas.add(new fabric.Image(imgObj))
                    };
                };
                reader.readAsDataURL(file);
            }
        }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/4.5.0/fabric.min.js"></script>
    <b> Image from Local PC: </b>
    <input id="fileInput" type="file" accept="image/*" onchange="Upload()" />
    <canvas id="canvas" width="1024px" height="576px" style="border:1px solid red"> </canvas>
```